# Team City 7 can't find DLL's in a project

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, teamcity, build-server, teamcity-7.0

I am trying to get our solution to work with Team City 7. I'm running into problems when Team City builds from the main solution (.sln) file. Once it reaches the project where we keep our unit tests, Team City spits out an error about not finding all sorts of DLL's like Gallio.dll, mbunit.dll etc.

Locally this project compiles fine though and all the references to these DLL's are set correctly. Why does Team City run into issues?

Error looks like this:

> General Logic\Language\LanguageLogicTests.cs(6, 7): error CS0246: The
>   type or namespace name 'Gallio' could not be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 4):

Have you referenced the test dlls from your local machine (e.g the GAC or c:\program files...) rather than from within your source tree? The references would then only be valid locally but not on your TC server.

It would be help if you posted that section from your csproj to verify this.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen the same issue on our environment with TeamCity 6.5. Sometimes somehow the references will not be added correctly to the .csproj but everything seems to be building correctly on your machine (due to GAC?).

When you open the .csproj and look at the references/hintpaths it might be incorrect. Verify this / post your .csproj